# Un-close question -- not off-topic?

Tags: support, reopen-request

The question I'm referring to is [Youtube etc. video problem](https://superuser.com/questions/209414/youtube-etc-video-problem)

Someone closed it as off-topic, probably under the impression that the question was about "a website" or "a web service". In fact, the question is about Adobe Flash player and there is a useful answer to the question ("update or reinstall graphic card drivers"), which I could just verify to solve the problem.

I am therefore convinced that it is actually on-topic as it is about "computer software" as stated in the FAQ, and would like to see it re-opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree too.

*Click Click Click*...

Open again! :-)

Answer (score 4):

I tend to agree, voting to reopen. Even though it's a rather "old" question, I agree it might be a software issue and it may yield some useful answers.